# Generalised binomial function

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, binomial-theorem

Given that
$$
\mathcal{B}_{t}(\boldsymbol{z})=\sum_{\mathrm{k} \ge 0}(tk)^{\underline{k-1}}\frac{z^k}{k!}.
$$
I should show that
$$
\mathcal{B}_{t}(z)^{1-t}-\mathcal{B}_{t}(z)^{-t}=z.
$$

I don't really know where to start ...

**Note:**
$$x^{\underline{k}}=\frac{x!}{(x-k)!}.$$

Comment: Hint: use Lagrange Inversion on $\mathcal{B}_t(z) = 1 + z \mathcal{B}_t(z)^t$ with careful book-keeping for negative $t.$

Comment: @MarkoRiedel I  have never heard of that but will now read about it, thanks!